# Необходимая пауза работы бота в ВКонтакте

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу на Python недавно и наверное не хватает опыта

Я пишу бота игру для ВКонтакте и в одном из сценариев мне необходимо создать искусственную паузу в работе бота, но я так понимаю что пауза создаться и для всех остальных пользователей бота. Хоть пауза нужна и пару секундная, но пользователь может ее создавать не один раз.

Так вот мне надо понять каким способом это можно обойти? Через отдельный поток мало представляю как это можно сделать, бот начнет отвечать на то что ненужно и вот даже не знаю...

Comment: Точно не уверен, но вы можете попробовать изучить процесс многопоточности в скрипте, типа действие будет направленно на определенного пользователя, как то так, лучше в интернете подробнее посмотрите, даже есть примеры из работы бота для телеграмма.

Comment: @ДанилкинPUBG Что-то я ничего толкового найти так и не смог

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать так называемый "Бан Пользователя для Бота", т.е. Бот будет игнорировать пользователя в основном скрипте.

После создайте скрипт, который по истечению времени снимет "Бан".

У меня такая штука есть